# Finding the next sibling by traversing a DOM Node

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I am trying to achieve this in a contenteditable div (TinyMCE) .

Goal : Find the nextSibling , if its null please go and get the parent's nextsibling .

Why ? To just stop the Delete Key to work if the next item is a div class="mceNonEditable" 
(I have the function to check if it mceNonEditable

My scope is restricted to TinyMCE div .

```
function findNextSibling(element)
    {
         if (element.parentNode.className == 'mceContentBody ') 
              {return element.nextSibling;} 
         else 
             {  if(element.nextSibling) {return element.nextSibling;} 
                else {return findNextSibling(element.parentNode);} 
                 }  
        }
```

Is there anything I am missing ?

I am getting an error like this in FireFox :

NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_OBJECT_ERR: Parameter is not an object
[Break On This Error]

rng.setStart(node.parentNode, idx);

Do I have an alternative way to do this ? I am not really looking for JQUERY if I can do this natively . Is the recursion code wrong ? Is it missing anything ?

Comment: `element` is probably not what you think.

Comment: Can you update your question and this fiddle with your existing code? http://jsfiddle.net/Fn6cV/8/